# Going to France via Geneva from Ireland

Tags: covid-19

We are traveling to France in August and planning to fly from Dublin to Geneva, hire a car in Geneva to travel to France. In terms of complying with Covid rules and testing, will we only have to comply with the requirements of flying into France?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166750/geneva-to-chamonix-with-french-issued-visa is a slightly different question but the answers touch upon this subject. In principle, the Swiss rules do apply but they might have provisions for transit.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to go through the Swiss part of the airport and the Swiss rules on customs, immigration and Covid-related restrictions all apply in principle. You cannot assume that only the French rules apply. In fact, you could probably ignore the French rules (not that I would advise it) whereas the airline and border police will enforce whatever restrictions the Swiss authorities have put in place.

In practice, Ireland is not currently on the [high-risk country list](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/sem/aktuell/faq-einreiseverweigerung.html#1668147653) from the Swiss Federal Department of Justice and Police and transit should be possible but that would be by virtue of Swiss rules not because traveling to France would allow you to ignore them.

Comment: well… the French tend to ignore the French rules so maybe this advise is not so far fetched after all.